# How to check if object matches with values on checkbox click?

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a function addToProduction. This loops over data and returns a new object with IDs and databases. The changeHandler on the checkbox currently displays all the values however I want to be able to log the correct id and database from the correct row and not all values. This will then be stored and appended to the databaseChanges array when clicked.

Comment: Do you want `addToProduction` to do *something* with the changed checkbox value, or to simply know which checkbox was changed via its id? Can you be a bit more explicit in what you want `addToProduction` to do with a specific checkbox?

Comment: I just want to know which checkbox was changed via its id. thanks!

Comment: so it will know which checkboc it was changed via its id then append it to the end of the databaseChanges array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the id from the `onChange` event object.

```
const addToProduction = e => {
  const { id } = e.target;

  ... // do whatever with id

  console.log(id)
}
```

And attach the test id to the checkbox `id` attribute

```
<Checkbox
  mainColor
  changeHandler={addToProduction}
  data={{}}
  id={test.id} // <-- attach id to checkbox
/>
```

**EDIT**

Pass entire `test` object to curried handler to append object into array. The curried function takes the `test` object and returns a function to be used as the callback (*now ignores the event object, but you can accept that if you need anything from it*).

```
const addToProduction = test => () => {
  const { databases, id } = test;

  console.log(databases, id)

  // append `{ id, databases }` to databaseChanges array
}
```

...

```
<Checkbox
  mainColor
  changeHandler={addToProduction(test)}
  data={{}}
/>
```

Comment: great thanks! How can I do this to include the database?

Comment: @bloombloom Is it related to the `databaseChanges` array in your snippet? You said you wanted the id so you could append *something* to the end of that array, but you didn't really specify anything else. I assumed you had the database side handled since it is mentioned in your post. What do you need to include?

Comment: Thanks Drew, essentially just like the test.id was logged, it will also have the test.database logged too.

Comment: In this case I suggest passing the `test` object to the handler. I'll update solution. How is `databaseChanges` instantiated and updated? Is it something in local component state? Parent state? What and where is it?

Comment: Database Changes is an object that has all test ids and databases from the parent state which is from the unitTestDatamap this is updated when I new id/database gets added.